# Form with post doesn't reach my function in django

Tags: html, django

I'm stuck with a st*pid question and problem.

I'm working with a form(html) on django, this form will be used to update information on my database regarding the page it's one.

So my problem is : django terminal tell me he receive the post correctly

```
app_1  | [10/Jan/2023 17:44:50] "GET /nb_database/49/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11810
app_1  | [10/Jan/2023 17:44:54] "POST /nb_database/49/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11810
```

However , i made a quick function to know my information from the form are coming to the function and here is the problem.
The function never print anything, i supposed the request never reach the function

Here is the function (located on the app named 'nb_database' :

```
def adding_address_to_db(request):
    print("OK REQUETE RECEIVE")
```

the urls.py (on the same app):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('nb_database', views.nb_database, name='nb_database'),
    path('nb_database/<int:annonce_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('nb_database/<int:annonce_id>/', views.adding_address_to_db, name='adding_address_to_db'),
]
```

And here is the form in HTML , for this example let's say it's on page mysite.com/nb_database/49/

```
<form action="" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %} 
       <input type="text" name="adding_address_to_db" placeholder="Entrez l'adresse" style="color: black;">  
</form>
```

Basically i want to be able to answer the form on the generated page (mysite.com/nb_database/49/) and stay on it once answered.

Any help will be welcome !
Thank's everyone, enjoy your day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so , i resolved my problem.

As said previously you can't have 2 urls pointing to 2 differents function on view.

I had to use the class Form provided by django.
Working with the post method and the form class i manage to add my function in the function who was generating the page and handle when a post method is send to catch the POST request and execute the code.

Here is a link to Django form documentation :
[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/)

And this is the kind of code i have to add to my rendering function :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 identical paths in urls.py. When you access `mysite.com/nb_database/49/`, only the function from the first path runs, not the second.
Remove this line and your function should run:

```
 path('nb_database/<int:annonce_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Comment: Also if the URL where your form is displayed is not the same as the URL where you are sending your POST request, you need to change the `action` attribute in your HTML to point to the URL where the POST request should be triggered. In this case: `<form action="{% url 'adding_address_to_db' %}" ...> ... </form>` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer Serguei , however i cannot remove this line, it's the one which generate the content of the page ("detail")

Comment: Thank you for answer vinkomlacic, the "adding_address_to_db" , is the name of the function, so there is not url to get there. It's on a python file name "views" in Django

Comment: Maybe i should have a new app in django to run this task ? This app will have another url different than the one which generate the page with all of his details

Comment: Use only one function in urls.py and then in views.py inside that function use if-else conditions to run different logic. It's explained quite well here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/